# Custom Button to send email no working

Tags: javascript, custom-button, send-email, onclick

I did create a custom button(OnClick JavaScript) to send an email. It is working fine with system admin. But when I did deploy it in production the users with profile other than system admin encountering an error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFDC_BigDog,

please enable the apex class access and visualforce pages access for that profile and check it again.

Setup->manageusers->profiles->scroll down and give acces to that particular pages and classes.

let me know if this helps and mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without your button code it's hard to answer, nevertheless I shall attempt it.

It looks like a permissions issue. I'm guessing you're referring to some custom class in your button code, and the profiles of some of your users do not have access to this class. Check the permissions of the profiles of the users experiencing this issue to see whether they have the required access.

If that doesn't help, please post your button code so we can analyse the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I did solved it. 
Here is the way to avoid this error.

Go to Setup->Develop->Apex Classses-> open the Class -> Click Security Button -> Add access to the profile from which you are trying to perform the action.